# Short story of a man whose reality would gradually become a weird dream

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read it years ago. It told the story of a man whose reality would gradually become a weird dream, while his dreams became as ordinary as real life can be.

At some point in the story, the concerned witnesses an incredible time jump, as his watch's hand moves instantly by half a dial or so...

I think he also had a psychologist monitoring his case.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More specifics would help, but could it be the novelette [*The Lathe of Heaven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lathe_of_Heaven) by Ursula Le Guin? The main character dreams of life in a fantastic city and by the end, that life becomes real while his mundane life at the start of the tale seems a dreamlike memory. There is indeed a psychologist monitoring the main character.

Comment: It looks like it I is, but I don't remember it was a novel. But rather a short story among other ones in a collection...

Comment: @Ibraz It is a novelette more than a novel, and according to the [Internet Speculative Fiction Data Base](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7661) has been collected into volumes with other works by Ursula Le Guin, including *The Wind's Twelve Quarters* which is properly an anthology of her early short fiction.

Comment: Thank you @Lexible. This is the one.

Comment: @Ibraz and other folks stopping by and reading me previous comment: it is collected into an omnibus **along with** *The Dispossessed* and *The Wind's Twelve Quarters*, but **is not** a part of the latter original anthology.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be ["Polaris"](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/p.aspx) by H.P. Lovecraft? The main character dreams of life in a fantastic city and by the end, that life seems real while his mundane life seems a dream.

Comment: No it is not Mgmills1968.
Thank you.